# For this BFS tree traversal, what does the "self" parameter in the queue for/doing?

Tags: python, tree, queue, traversal, breadth-first-search

I am new to python programming and still trying to understand the concept of self.

In this breadth-first-search traversal, I want to know what the "self" passed into the queue as parameter mean.

```
class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left_child = None
        self.right_child = None


    def bfs(self):
        queue = Queue()
        queue.put(self)

        while not queue.empty():
            current_node = queue.get()
            print(current_node.value)

            if current_node.left_child:
                queue.put(current_node.left_child)

            if current_node.right_child:
    queue.put(current_node.right_child)
```

Comment: go through this it might help https://www.programiz.com/article/python-self-why

Comment: Typically, `self` is the first argument to functions which are members of a class, and it refers to the current class instance.  However your code does not appear to be part of a class.

Comment: I did not include the binary tree class

Comment: So, for explain the `self` you need to post here the entire class